# Use of new command resets page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I defined a command in the preamble that allows something to be repeated n times

```
\def\myrepeat#1#2{\count0=#1 \loop \ifnum\count0>0 \advance\count0 by -1 #2\repeat}
```

so 
        \myrepeat{3}{foo} 
is the same as typing 
        foofoofoo.

Every time I use the \myrepeat command in the body, the page numbering is reset to 0. Why is that happening, and is there an easy way to fix this?

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\irepeat#1#2{\count0=#1 \loop \ifnum\count0>0 \advance\count0 by -1 #2\repeat}

\begin{document}
The page number here is 1.
\newpage
\irepeat{3}{foo}
The page number here is 0.
\newpage
And 1 again.
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use another count, `count4` for example.

Comment: Using a different count solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Sigur Out of curiosity, was the issue that `\count` by default calls the "first" counter, which is the page counter?

Comment: `\thepage` is `\csname @arabic\endcsname \c@page` and `\c@page` is `\count0`.

Comment: For temporary storage, use `\count255` rather than `\count0`; note that the values of `\count0` to `\count9` are stored in the DVI or PDF file during shipout of a page.

Answer (score 7):

The counter `\count0` stores the current page number, so it's not a good idea to use it for temporary storage; it could be by enclosing the code in a group, but it's not recommended if something is to be printed, because printing a paragraph may trigger the page builder at unexpected times and so give the page the wrong number.

LaTeX provides two counters for temporary storage, `\@tempcnta` and `\@tempcntb`; one can also use `\count@`, which is the same as `\count255`.

There are better ways to print repeated copies of a token list. The simplest one is with LaTeX3 features:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\irepeat}{ m m }
{
 \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\irepeat{3}{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\numexpr` and standard LaTeX techniques it could be

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\irepeat}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>\z@
    #2%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {\expandafter\irepeat\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\irepeat{3}{foo}

\end{document}
```

With a loop

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\irepeat[2]{%
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax % or \@tempcntb or \count@
  \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@
    \advance\@tempcnta by \m@ne
    #2%
  \repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\irepeat{3}{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This reminds me of http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl3.pdf

Comment: @cgnieder Of course: `\prg_replicate:nn` is based on a similar idea.

Comment: @cgnieder David K. recently pointed out an issue with a 'simple' e-TeX approach in _Die TeXnische Komödie_

Comment: @Joseph yes, I remember